# URL GET/POST Request objective-c

Tags: objective-c, url, post, get, request

I have to send get or post request to localhost:

```
<?php
 if(@$_GET['option']) {
  echo "You said \"{$_GET['option']}\"";
 }else if(@$_POST['option']) {
  echo "You said \"{$_POST['option']}\"";
 }
?>
```

ive using this code:

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/wsh/index.php?option=Hello"]];
 NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
 NSString *get = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:response encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

it works, but one time in code. if ill do it another one time, application has terminate.

Im try to use ASIFormDataRequest:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [[[ASIFormDataRequest alloc] initWithURL:@"http://localhost/wsh/index.php"] autorelease];
[request setPostValue:@"option" forKey:@"myFormField1"];
[request start];
NSError *error = [request error];
if (!error) {
  NSString *response = [request responseString];
  NSLog(response);
}else{
  NSLog(@"error");
}
```

it says:

```
2010-01-07 13:20:34.964 WSH[3351:903] -[NSCFString absoluteURL]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x160f8
2010-01-07 13:20:34.966 WSH[3351:903] error
```

sry for my english

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are using a plain `NSString` literal where an `NSURL` object is expected: [...] `initWithURL:@"http://localhost/wsh/index.php"` [...]

Change this to `initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/wsh/index.php"]`.

Answer (score 6):

I wonder if also you should switch the value and key for the post values, ie change the line

```
[request setPostValue:@"option" forKey:@"myFormField1"];
```

to

```
[request setPostValue:@"myFormField1" forKey:@"option"];
```